# Classification of samples with less input variables than the neural network was trained with

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, panel-data

I have trained a feedforward neural network with 12 input features of longitudinal (time-series) data. The data is one-dimensional but it is observed at 12 evenly spaced time points. How can I classify a sample with less observations than 12 observations, for example, only 8 observations using my trained neural network? I know this type of problems are usually solved with reccurrent neural networks, **but is it possible to classify a sample with less observed variables than the feedforward network is trained with?** Or do I need to use a recurrent neural network? Im not interested in predicting new values, only to which curve the green sample belongs to.

Pictures to illustrade my problem. The first picture shows 2 samples and which curve they belong to (by color). The network is trained with samples like this, all having 12 observations each.

The second picture illustrates the two curves together with a sample with only 8 observation, and I want to classify this to correct curve. Is this possible with my trained feedforward neural network? Or do I need to use a RNN for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try to interpolate/extrapolate as many values as you are missing. Not sure how well that would work in practice though.

Comment: How often do you expect to make predictions for incomplete time series (as opposed to complete ones)?

Comment: @dipetkov I can't really answer that, since I treat that as two different problems. I want to see how good my fully trained network is for classifying incomplete samples. For example, the curves could model "true" blood levels of a healthy/sick patient, and I want to be able to predict if a patient will become sick. Given observed blood levels early on in a medical treatment, I want to classify if the patient belong to curve1 (= healthy) or curve2 (= sick).

Comment: Not to discourage you from trying this out but your two examples are most "distinguishable" on the right. If that's true for most examples, then the "full" model puts a lot of weight on how the series behave towards the end. So a model trained on times 1:8 might actually do better at classification at time 8 than the full model, whatever scheme you come up with to impute the missing values 9:12.

Comment: @dipetkov I came to the same conclusion sort of, and I shall look into recurrent neural networks instead. Either way, thanks for your input!